# Query a firebase firestore db where collection have an object with references

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question regarding the firestore db from firebase.

I have a document X that contains a field called users that is an object with references to users inside the users collection.

It looks simular to this:

```
families: [{
    xyz: {
        name:'foobar',
        users: {
            john: 'users/john', //reference to another document 
            mike: 'users/mike'  //reference to another document
        }
    }   
},
...]
```

How can I query the firestore db to get all documents (from the families collection) that have a user with the name 'john'?

I tried the following without luck:

```
db.collection('families')
.where('users.john', '<', '')
```

But it only returns an empty array.

If I switch the users entry from key:reference to key:string object it works. But I want to work with refrences and not strings.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore doesn't provide a way to query for the simple existence of fields.  The indexes it uses to find documents are based on the *values* of a property.  Right now, your values are document references, so you can only query against their reference values.

If you want to know if a something exists in a document, you could create a new field for it with a boolean value.  You can then query that for true or false.

```
families: [{
    xyz: {
        name:'foobar',
        users: {
            john: 'users/john', //reference to another document 
            mike: 'users/mike'  //reference to another document
        },
        users_exists: {
            john: true,
            mike: true
        }
    }
},
```

With users_exists in place above, now you can query like this:

```
db.collection('families')
.where('users_exists.john', '==', true)
```

The general rule for NoSQL data modeling is to do it in whatever way suits the queries you intend to perform.  Sometimes this involves duplicating data to suit those queries.

Comment: Thanks, but then it is easier to change the data in user to a key value map with strings for key and value. Since you can use the following query to check if it exists.  

    db.collection('families').where('users.john', '<', '')

Comment: what is the complexity of this query? does it scan the entire table, or does it keep some effective index for the values?

Comment: @thebeancounter There are no "table scans" in Firestore.  It will refuse to do queries that aren't satisfied by an optimized index.

Comment: @DougStevenson - so what am i missing here? seems in your answer that you are using "where" on a field in a map, when did it become an optimized index?

Comment: All single fields are automatically indexed, unless you disable that.

Comment: And how are values inside a field that is a map indexed? and another thing, if the default is that everything is indexed, why can i create a new single field index?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. It's not important to understand *how* indexing works, just *that* it works.