# python firebase update items using where query

Tags: python, database, firebase

I am using python with firebase, and have a table, I need to update all items that have a specific value in a field, I found out how to query for all the items having that value [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49140166/query-a-firebase-firestore-db-where-collection-have-an-object-with-references)

Now I need to update all the items that I get in return.

What I would like to do, is to use a single query to perform a single operation that will find the correct items using the where query, and update a certain field to a certain value, I need that functionality in order to keep some data consistent.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about Realtime Database or Firestore? In both cases, you can't update data with a query.  You have to query, then update.

Comment: please post an answer for me to recieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do it, but in more steps:

```py
# the usual preparation
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
databaseURL = {'databaseURL': "https://<YOUR-DB>.firebaseio.com"}
cred = credentials.Certificate("<YOUR-SERVICE-KEY>.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, databaseURL)
database = firestore.client()
col_ref = database.collection('<YOUR-COLLECTION>')

# Query generator for the documents; get all people named Pepe
results = col_ref.where('name', '==', 'Pepe').get()
# Update Pepe to José
field_updates = {"name": "José"}
for item in results:
  doc = col_ref.document(item.id)
  doc.update(field_updates)
```

(I use Cloud Firestore, maybe it is different in Realtime Database)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the query and find the DocumentReference in each iteration.

```
    db = firestore.client()

    a= request_json['message']['a']
    b= request_json['message']['b']
    

    ref = db.collection('doc').where(a'', u'==', u'a').stream()
    for i in ref: 
        i.reference.update({"c":"c"}) # get the document reference and use it to update\delete ...
```